# Origin of "poindexter/pointdexter"

Tags: etymology, slang

Was this term (I believe it is a synonym of *geek*, *nerd*, and so on) based on the television series *Dexter* or was it around before that and the series based its name on it?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=poindexter

Comment: The name *Dexter* is not derived from Poindexter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been around a lot longer than the TV series *Dexter*.

> [**poindexter**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=poindexter)
>
> “nerdy intellectual,” by 1986, U.S. teenager slang, from the character
>   Poindexter, introduced 1959 in the made-for-TV cartoon version of
>   “Felix the Cat.”

The TV series is based on the novels by [Jeff Lindsay](http://bookbitch.blogspot.com/2009_11_15_archive.html):

> One of the most interesting questions came from a librarian. She asked
>   whether Dexter's name came from "dexterous", meaning left handed, and
>   "sinister", meaning right handed. Lindsay was stunned, saying it was
>   only the second time he's ever been asked this. She was correct - he
>   said the book's original title was the "Left Hand of God".

Although *dexter* is really Latin for right and *sinister* is Latin for left. From [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Dexter) (click "open/close all folders"):

> Meaningful Name: In Latin *Dexter* means right and is the opposite of
>   Left, which is *Sinister*. The main character must follow the Code of
>   Harry so as to appear as Dexter and not let on that he is Sinister.
>
> - Also, Dexter refers to dexterity. Defined by the Merriam-Webster
>     dictionary as: "mental skill or quickness / readiness and grace in
>     physical activity; especially : skill and ease in using the hands."
> - Probably not intentional, but dextrose is a more scientific term for blood sugar [sic, blood sugar is glucose, not dextrose].

Comment: I am wondering where the reversal has crept into the quote above: "dexter" in Latin is the *right* hand, and "sinister" the left.

Comment: @Hugo, the quote from the blog is really low quality and just adds nothing to the explanation (except confusion).

Comment: Yes, I was wondering the same thing too. I had thought he was called Dexter as he may be a serial killer, but he's a serial killer with a moral code (the opposite of sinister). And he's dexterous with a knife. I've found something else and will make an edit.

Comment: A precise and exact answer looks pretty definite and permanent, don't understand why the question got closed. Well thanks anyway!

Comment: Dextrose does mean blood sugar, too—it is just less commonly used than glucose. It is actually a shortening of ‘dextro-glucose’, so called because it polarises light to the right in spectroscopy (Etymonline—didn't know that last bit, and probably don't understand it either).